# "Magic: the Gathering" Challenge #1: A Fiendish Puzzle

Tags: calculation-puzzle, magic-the-gathering

<sub>[Next Challenge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23959/mtg-challenge-2-two-peas-in-a-pod)</sub>

**BACKGROUND:**
Here's a puzzle for Magic: the Gathering players out there. I feel that this puzzle is in the scope of the site, and is no different than other puzzles, e.g. chess, which require knowledge of the parameters of a game in order to solve. I'm adding the MtG tag since I hope to do more of these in the future. I've linked to cards so that you don't have to go look them up yourself. For those interested in learning the rules of Magic, see [here](http://magic.wizards.com/en/game-info/gameplay/how-to-play) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic:_The_Gathering).

This first one will be reasonably easy; I've tried to ensure that there is only one correct answer. Please don't post an answer unless it's distinct i.e. isn't just another answer but with mana tapped slightly differently or two spells cast in swapped orders if it doesn't affect the outcome. If I missed something, and there are multiple *distinct* solutions, I will accept the one that gets the most damage through.

**PUZZLE SETUP:**
It is Main Phase 1 of your turn. You've just drawn and haven't played a land for the turn. Defeat your opponent during this turn (before end of cleanup step). Provide the sequence of spells/game actions that you take to achieve the goal. Please be specific about mana usage / land tapping (feel free to keep a count of mana between steps)

#### Your hand:

[Gitaxian Probe](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=233056)
[Gitaxian Probe](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=233056)
[Serum Visions](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=50145)
[Sure Strike](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=402052)
[Twinflame](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=380523)

#### Your board:

[Kiln Fiend](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=292742) (no summoning sickness)

1 Island, 2 Mountain all untapped

10 life

#### Your opponent's hand:

Nothing

#### Your opponent's board:

Nothing

50 life

#### Your Library (top to bottom):

[Assault Strobe](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=194119)
[Brute Force](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397729)
[Lightning Bolt](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397722)
[Manamorphose](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370568)
[Preordain](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=405347)
Island
[Brainstorm](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=405158)
Mountain
[Thought Scour](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=380203)
[Lava Spike](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370409)
[Grapeshot](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370472)

Comment: Edited hand and opponents life total since puzzle was originally mistyped

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is essentially the same as the other answer, but using both Probes and with Brute Force instead of Sure Strike.

1. Serum Visions (Draw Assault Strobe, put Lightning Bolt on bottom, leave Brute Force on top. RR)
2. Gitaxian Probe (Draw Brute Force. Pay life. RR)
3. Gitaxian Probe (Draw Manamorphose. Pay life. RR)
4. Manamorphose (Draw Preordain, create UR. UR)
5. Preordain (Put Brainstorm and Island on bottom, draw Mountain. R)
6. Mountain (RR)
7. Brute Force (R)
8. Assault Strobe

1+21 from seven spells, and another +3 from Brute Force, x2 makes 50 damage.

Comment: Nicely done spellslinger! Challenge 2 is up