# "Magic: the Gathering" Challenge #4: Stuck in the Grenzone

Tags: calculation-puzzle, magic-the-gathering

<sub>[Previous Challenge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23996/magic-the-gathering-challenge-3-legends-rule)</sub>

<sub>[Next Challenge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24081/magic-the-gathering-challenge-5-revenge-of-the-pod)</sub>

#### BACKGROUND:

The usual magic rules apply here. Please don't post a solution that if a solution for more damage already exists. Please be explicit in mana usage in your solution. I've tried to ensure that there are no infinite loops available, but if I somehow missed one (that Kiki-Jiki's always causing trouble), please inform me and I'll remove the required components from the puzzle.

For this puzzle, assume that unless otherwise modified, the bottom of your library will always be 50 mountains, regardless of shuffling. Similarly, assume that beneath any cards deliberately placed on the top of your library, there will always be 50 mountains regardless of shuffling. Basically, you can't just activate Grenzo blindly and say that you hit whatever you want. Cards on the top or bottom cannot be assumed to exist there unless deliberately placed there in your solution.

Oh and for those wondering, no, the punny titles will not stop as long as I can help it.

#### PUZZLE SETUP:

It is your main phase 1. You have just had a [Goblin Recruiter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=15417) enter the battlefield (don't worry about how, it's magic) and are about to resolve its ability. Defeat your opponent this turn by doing as much damage as possible! The solution that gets the most damage through wins. I won't tell my current best record as I don't want to dissuade other answers that do less damage from getting posted initially, but suffice to say that it is in the triple digits.

**Your hand:**
[Demonic Tutor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=394025)
[Brightstone Ritual](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=39846)

**Your board: (all untapped; recruiter has summoning sickness, the others do not)**
[Grenzo, Dungeon Warden](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=382276) with a +1/+1 counter, making it a 3/3
[Viscera Seer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=376569)
[Sol Ring](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=405389)
[Goblin Recruiter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=15417)
1 Forest
2 Mountain
2 Swamp

5 life

**Your graveyard:**
Nothing

**Your library:**
[Adaptive Automaton](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=220147)
[Battle Squadron](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=19712)
[Beetleback Chief](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=389439)
[Blazing Shoal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=74441)
[Brightstone Ritual](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=39846)
[Chasm Guide](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=401840)
[Clickslither](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=393945)
[Coat of Arms](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397422)
[Door of Destinies](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370699)
[Empty the Warrens](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370480)
[Goblin Bushwhacker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=177501)
[Goblin Chieftain](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=221201)
[Goblin Clearcutter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=44317)
[Goblin General](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=382957)
[Goblin King](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=129578)
[Goblin Lookout](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=45123)
[Goblin Marshal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=15212)
[Goblin Matron](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=393962)
[Goblin Ringleader](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=393963)
[Goblin War Marshal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=393973)
[Goblin War Strike](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=44292)
[Goblin Warchief](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=393965)
[Goblin Wardriver](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=213782)
[Goblin Welder](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=389537)
[Hall of Triumph](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=380431)
[Heartstone](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=207924)
[Hellraiser Goblin](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=386327)
[Kiki-Jiki, Mirror Breaker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397698)
[Krenko, Mob Boss](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=386339)
100 Mountain
[Murderous Redcap](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370518)
[Reckless Charge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=383062)
[Reckless One](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=393981)
[Siege-Gang Commander](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=393982)
[Vampiric Tutor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=383145)
[Warren Instigator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=191368)
[Zada, Hedron Grinder](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=402100)

**Opponent's hand:**
Nothing

**Opponent's board:**
Nothing

20 life

**Opponent's graveyard:**
Nothing

Comment: Is your statement to say that the Goblin Recruiter *does* have summoning sickness through this magical appearance, or can he attack this turn? How many tokens does Grenzo have on him at the moment?

Comment: @IanMacDonald thanks, forgot to copy over grenzo's p/t. As for the recruiter, it has summoning sickness.

Comment: What would the rules say about Battle Squadron and Reckless One wrt Grenzo's ability?

Comment: @IanMacDonald 208.2a The card may have a characteristic-defining ability that sets its power and/or toughness
according to some stated condition. (See rule 604.3.) Such an ability is worded “[This
creature’s] [power or toughness] is equal to . . .” or “[This creature’s] power and toughness are
each equal to . . .” This ability functions everywhere, even outside the game.

Comment: Okay. I guess I meant more like can Battle Squadron be summoned first by Grenzo when there are three creatures on the board, or does it count itself immediately, making its power 4/4 causing Grenzo to be unable to summon it?

Comment: Ah I see. Both refer to the number of creaures on the field (squadron is specifically those you control, but still) neither of them consider themselves when Grenzo checks their power, as they're still in the graveyard.

Comment: I assume it's not possible to attack with Clickslither and a goblin, then sacrifice the goblin after its damage resolves, but before Clickslither's damage resolves?

Comment: @IanMacDonald correct, this is not possible because their damage happens simultaneously (since neither has first/double strike) and does not use the stack (since M10 or something) so the damage does not 'resolve' it all just happens

Comment: If you were smart and chose to play your Demonic Tutor before resolving Recruiter so as to avoid later messing with the order, you can do surprisingly well with a tutor for a second Brightstone Ritual.  It doesn't beat the top answer below, but it comes close, in the range of ~ [400 damage](http://i.imgur.com/aRYXFGP.png).  This might be improvable by using Kiki-Jiki later on to copy Lookout, but you still won't go over 475; there simply aren't enough pump effects, and there's no way to combine this with Zada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some slight improvements to the solution DrunkWolf used (I don't feel too bad about the similarities, I swear I came up with the base solution independently).

Goblin Recruiter puts the following on top of my library:

- Goblin Marshal
- Kiki-Jiki, Mirror Breaker
- Goblin Chieftain
- Krenko, Mob boss
- Goblin Clearcutter
- Goblin Ringleader
- Goblin Welder

Tap everything for [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]]
Sacrifice Recruiter to Viscera seer to scry Marshal to the bottom, then activate Grenzo to get Marshal (2 tokens) [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]]
Sacrifice a token to bottom Kiki-Jiki, then activate Grenzo to get Kiki (1 token) [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]]
Tap Kiki to copy Marshal (3 tokens)
Sacrifice both Marshals to bottom Chieftain and Krenko (7 tokens)
Cast Brightstone Ritual [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]]
Activate Grenzo twice to get Chieftain and Krenko [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]]
Sacrifice Kiki-Jiki to bottom Clearcutter
Activate Grenzo to get Clearcutter [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]]
Tap Clearcutter for three red [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]]
Sacrifice Clearcutter to bottom Ringleader
Activate Grenzo to get Ringleader, putting Goblin Welder into your hand. [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]]
Cast Goblin Welder [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]]
You now control Grenzo, Chieftain, Krenko, Ringleader, Welder and 7 tokens.  Activate Krenko for 12 tokens
Cast Demonic Tutor getting Vampiric Tutor [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]]
Cast Vampiric Tutor putting Coat of Arms on top [image: ]][image: ]]
Sacrifice Viscera Seer to bottom Coat of Arms
Activate Grenzo to put Coat of Arms into the graveyard
Activate Goblin Welder to swap Sol Ring for Coat of Arms

Attack with 27/27 Grenzo, 26/26 Ringleader, 25/25 Chieftain and nineteen 25/25 tokens, for a total of 553.

Comment: That's the same answer I got (with a few sacrifices in different orders), but I have one correction.  That's not 553 damage it's 531 - I suspect you misread Coat of Arms; it adds for each *other* creature, so that's only +22/+22 for all of them, +1/+1 from Chieftain.

Comment: There's 24 goblins, so it's giving +23/23. Grenzo, Ringleader, Chieftain, Krenko, Welder, 19 tokens.

Comment: Oh... right you are, I dropped a goblin on my end.  Krenko, I believe - he seems to have gone missing after I tapped him.

Comment: After some thought, I'm fairly certain this is the optimal solution.  Pre-ritual, you need to maximize goblin count and the only alternative is Marshal > Seige Gang, but Kiki-Jiki can't copy Krenko so it's otherwise worthless.  Might as well use it up here for the two bonus scrys. Anything that involves more than two Grenzo activations cuts off BB, so you can't get Coat of Arms profitably later.  Post ritual, you need Haste (-2), Krenko (-2), and Welder (-1/-2), with (+1) off Clearcutter.  That leaves you with 1 (nothing) or 2 (in which case, it has to be ringleader for Welder).

Comment: I agree with your assessment, but to clarify, more than two Grenzo activations pre-ritual cuts off even single B (you have to leave R floating to cast the ritual). The only other approach is to start by getting Chieftain and Clearcutter, and that's just terrible.

Comment: Right, Chieftain > Clearcutter > Seige-Gang or Marshal is the alternative.  And yes, it's much worse - and even if it weren't, it still cuts you off BB, which costs you (2) down the road as well.  As an aside, Coat of Arms is definitely the best play, with second and third place going to "Zada + Pump" and "Tutor for second Ritual".  Not sure which is better, but they're not close to Coat.

Comment: When I read the clear cutter first time I noted to myself he had to be in.. But when I posted later he slipped my mind, good job!

Comment: I really want Warren Instigator in here, as he's "free" in that he costs (RR), but adds a goblin that would also have cost (2) before second strike damage occurs (gaining damage equal to his first strike hit) and our last plays are instant speed.  Unfortunately, he can only be played alongside Ringleader to get available Goblins into our hand.  This means we must use 93's answer, and the only Goblins he can get are Krenko (too late for tokens to attack), Clearcutter (if done last, he eats up your black mana), Welder (where he only saves 1; not enough), and Chieftain (fails on multiple levels).

Comment: Well unless someone blows my mind, I think it's safe to say this is the optimal answer. Awesome work on improving on the 462/3 solution! Challenge 5 is up if you think you're up for it

Answer (score 3):

Here's mine

Goblin Recruiter puts on top of library, in order from top to bottom:

- Goblin Marshal
- Kiki-Jiki, Mirror Breaker
- Goblin Chieftain
- Krenko, Mob boss

Tap everything, in mana pool: [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]]

1. Viscera seer the recruiter, Marshal on bottom.
2. Activate Grenzo, put Marshal in play, 2 tokens [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]]
3. Viscera seer a token, Kiki-Jiki on bottom. -1 token
4. Activate Grenzo, put Kiki jiki in play, active to copy Marshal, +2 tokens. (Tapped kiki, 2 Marshals, 3 tokens)[image: ]][image: ]][image: ]]
5. Viscera seer both marshals, +4 tokens, Chieftan and Krenko on bottom.
6. Brightstone ritual, 9 goblins total (Kiki, 7 tokens, Grenzo) [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]]
7. Activate Grenzo x2, Chieftain and Krenko in play (11 goblins total) [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]]
8. Activate Krenko, +11 goblins (Kiki, Krenko (both tapped), Grenzo, 18 tokens, Chieftan)
9. Demonic tutor Coat of Arms, hardcast, all goblins +21/+21 from coat (and 1 from the chieftain)
10. Attack with 20 goblins, Grenzo is 25/25, rest is 23/23 and the seer

**Total damage: 463**

Comment: You beat me to this answer by three minutes, good job. I don't think this can be beaten.

Comment: @Ninety-Three don't think so either, quadratic effect from coat is just to strong. And I think this solution maxes the amount of goblins

Comment: Because pictures! Why not.

Comment: My solution goes a slightly different route (get welder, demonic tutor for vamp tutor, vamp for coat of arms, scry to bottom, activate grenzo to put in gy, welder it in to play in exchange for sol ring), but ends up at the exact same damage amount (5 mana required to vamp, activate for welder, and activate for coat is the same as just hardcasting, and the scry costs a goblin anyways so net goblin count is the same). I couldn't find a better line myself. Also, dem mana symbols

Comment: @DrunkWolf Had a suspicion there was a better answer using coat of arms, simple one I'd worked out was less than 100 damage, which is why I went without.

Comment: @IanMacDonald You're confusing B with U in the images, can't cast demonic with blue mana :(

Comment: I really wanted the solution to involve Goblin Ringleader + Warchief, but you're so tight on mana the only way to fit it in requires cutting Krenko and that's obviously no good.

Comment: @DrunkWolf I clearly got caught up in figuring out what blue was since both black and blue share B. Obviously, it should have been black. :)

Comment: @Ninety-Three Yup, the tight restriction on mana basically spells out the solution. It would diversify a lot with extra lands.

Comment: @DrunkWolf would it? I'm not sure; if you had another 2 lands for example, I think you just add siege-gang commander to the existing solution. With 4 lands, you add commander+beetleback chief. I just don't think there's a way to beat coat of arms + max goblins

Comment: @NeedAName you could consider using Krenko pre ritual for more mana an you get 2 more activations after ritual as well out of siege, ofcourse every solution would still use coat

Comment: @NeedAName I just mean that you would be less focused on getting arms/krenko/haste out (which you know you always have to do) and had more freedom with the 'support cast', which might have less straightforward options. That said: Really enjoying your puzzles so far, they're a welcome addition to puzzling for me :)

Comment: @DrunkWolf I see what you mean. Glad you're enjoying, I'm just happy I made one with no mistakes for once. How did you guys feel about the difficulty on this one? Reasonable? I've got a real doozie in the works currently and am starting to wonder if I should ease up on it

Comment: @NeedAName difficulty wise this would be a 2/5 I think, crank it up to 5 ;p

Comment: This one was pretty easy, easier than the Birthing Pod one because here it's easy to discard most of the red herrings. More doozies please!

Comment: @NeedAName Forgot to attack with seer, beat you by 1 dmg :P (Since you needed to sac the seer for the last scry :D)

Comment: @DrunkWolf Indeed seems that you come out ahead by one. Great spot!

Comment: Hah, not only did I beat this with a few improvements, I won the moral victory of fitting in Ringleader (Grenzo for Ringleader for Welder instead of plain Grenzo for Welder, because I had a mana to spare and it boosts the goblin count).

Answer (score 1):

Figured I'd put up an answer, though I don't know if it's optimal.

Goblin Recruiter puts on top of library, in order from top to bottom:

1. Siege-Gang Commander
2. Kiki-Jiki, Mirror Breaker
3. Goblin Ringleader
4. Warren Instigator
5. Goblin Marshal
6. Goblin Chieftain
7. Zada, Hedron Grinder
8. Krenko, Mob Boss

   - Sacrifice Goblin Recruiter to Viscera Seer, scrying Siege-Gang Commander to bottom of library.
   - Tap Sol Ring, use 2 mana to activate Grenzo, putting Siege-Gang Commander into play, getting three 1/1 Goblins.
   - Sacrifice goblin token to Viscera Seer, scrying Kiki-Jiki to bottom of library.
   - Tap Forest and Swamp, use mana to activate Grenzo, putting Kiki-Jiki into play.
   - Activate Kiki-Jiki targetting Siege-Gang Commander, putting three goblin tokens into play.
   - Board: 2 Siege-Gang Commanders, 5 goblin tokens, Viscera Seer, Tapped Kiki-Jiki, Grenzo, 2 Mountains, 1 Swamp untapped.
   - Cast Brightstone Ritual, tapping a mountain, adding 9 red mana to your mana pool.
   - Sacrifice Kiki-Jiki, scrying Goblin Ringleader to the bottom of your library.
   - Use two red mana to activate Grenzo, putting Goblin Ringleader into play, drawing Warren Instigator, Zada, Hedron Grinder, Goblin Marshal, and Goblin Chieftain.
   - Sacrifice Viscera Seer, scrying Krenko, Mob Boss to the bottom of your library.
   - Use two red mana to activate Grenzo, putting Krenko, Mob Boss into play.
   - Board: 2 Siege-Gang Commander, 5 goblin tokens, Goblin Ringleader, Grenzo, Krenko, Mob Boss, Untapped Mountain and Swamp, 5 red mana floating.
   - Use two red mana to cast Warren Instigator
   - Use three red mana to cast Goblin Chieftain
   - Use Swamp and Mountain to cast Demonic Tutor, putting Blazing Shoal into hand.
   - Board: 2Siege-Gang Commanders, 5 goblin tokens, Goblin Ringleader, Grenzo, Krenko Mob Boss, Warren Instigator, Goblin Chieftain.
   - Activate Krenko Mob Boss, making 12 goblin tokens.
   - Attack with 2 Siege-Gang Commander, 17 goblin tokens, Goblin Ringleader, Grenzo, Warren Instigator, Goblin Chieftain.
   - Warren Instigator triggers on first-strike damage, putting Zada, Hedron Grinder into play.
   - Still in first strike damage step, cast Blazing Shoal pitching Goblin Marshal, targetting Zada, Hedron Grinder for +6/+0.
   - All your creatures have +6/+0 in regular damage step.

Total Damage: **2** Warren Instigator first strike damage + **19*8** Damage (Warren Instigator regular damage, Goblin Chieftain, 17 goblin tokens) + **3*9** Damage (2 Siege-Gang Commanders, Goblin Ringleader) + **10** Grenzo Damage

Total Damage: **191**

Answer improved with tip by Drunkwolf.

Comment: You would get more damage if you put out siege-gang and kiki-jiki copying the siege-gang (same amount of total goblins), then pitching the marshall to the shoal later.

Comment: @Drunkwolf That is actually true. May wish to post your own answer? Don't want to take your idea.

Comment: I'll post my own later, don't worry :) feel free to use the tip in yours though