# "Magic: the Gathering" Challenge #5: What if Pod was One of Us

Tags: calculation-puzzle, magic-the-gathering

<sub>[Previous Challenge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24040/magic-the-gathering-challenge-4-stuck-in-the-grenzone)</sub>

<sub>[Next Challenge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24240/magic-the-gathering-challenge-6-b-its-gonna-cost-you)</sub>

#### BACKGROUND:

The usual magic rules apply here. Please be explicit in mana usage in your solution where relevant. I've tried to ensure that there are no infinite loops available, but if I somehow missed one, please inform me.

If you draw any cards, you may assume that you draw whatever cards you require that are still in your library, regardless of shuffling.

You guys asked for a hard one so here it is. This is going to be a pretty difficult one and may involve some complex interactions. Be sure to be careful with all steps and read all cards carefully. If you're fuzzy on a rule/interaction, [here is the comprehensive rulebook](http://magic.wizards.com/en/gameinfo/gameplay/formats/comprehensiverules) and [here is the mtg judge chat](http://chat.magicjudges.org/mtgrules/) where you can ask rulings questions that you can't find on the web.

All permanents in the given setup below are owned by their controllers (recall that if a player loses the game, all permanents they own are removed from the game regardless of who controls them at the time)

Your solution may not assume that an opponent will cooperate with you in some way (e.g. choose not to block when they have legal blockers). Your solution must be able to win regardless of any potential blocks made by your opponents.

#### PUZZLE SETUP:

It's a game of 3-for-all! You're behind on life and on board and your opponents are trying to lock the game down.

It is your main phase 1. Given the board state given below, defeat both of your opponents this turn!

**Your hand:**
[Pull from Eternity](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=106657)

**Your board: (all untapped; all permanents have been in continuous control since beginning turn)**
2 [Birthing Pod](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=218006)
[Kitchen Finks](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370458) (with no counters)
25 Mountain
5 Swamp
1 Plains

25 life

**Your graveyard:**
[Necropede](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=194052)

**Your library:**
23 Swamp
[Glistener Elf](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=233052)
[Hapless Researcher](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=36115)
[Nature's Chosen](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=3146)
[Qasali Pridemage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=249405)
[Dross Harvester](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=50537)
[Kathari Bomber](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=386337)
[Laboratory Maniac](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=230788)
[Shade's Form](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=23043)
[Village Bell-Ringer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=222923)
[Academy Rector](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=15138)
[Arcum Dagsson](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=122124)
[Clever Impersonator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=386506)
[March of the Machines](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=220529)
[Phyrexian Metamorph](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=214375)
[Xenograft](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=227544)
[Cryptic Gateway](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=39701)
[Karmic Guide](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=382983)
[Phyrexian Delver](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=376446)
[Sky Hussar](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=97109)
[Auratouched Mage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=271207)
[Sun Titan](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=405400)
[Angel of Serenity](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=405126)
[Boonweaver Giant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=383194)
[Sepulchral Primordial](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=366285)
[Gigantomancer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=198172)
[Trench Gorger](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=228242)

**Opponent 1's hand:**
Nothing

**Opponent 1's board: (all untapped)**
[Blood Reckoning](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=279991)
[Peacekeeper](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=4584)
2 [Silent Arbiter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=382362)

60 life

**Opponent 1's graveyard:**
[Hamlet Captain](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=234446)
[Rage Weaver](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=130997)
[Voice of Resurgence](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=368951)
[Hellrider](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=368530)
[Phage the Untouchable](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=382324)

**Opponent 2's hand:**
Nothing

**Opponent 2's board: (all untapped)**
2 [Ghostly Prison](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=275264)
[Windborn Muse](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=247147)
Activated [Jace, Architect of Thought](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=253653)'s +1 last turn. The Jace is no longer on the field, but in the graveyard

44 life

**Opponent 2's graveyard:**
[Lightning Mauler](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=271119)
[Silverblade Paladin](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=389673)
[Hero of Bladehold](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=214064)
[Jace, Architect of Thought](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=253653) that activated +1 last turn

**All Exiles:**
Nothing

Comment: Suggestion would be to sort Library by CMC again, like the last Pod puzzle. Helped a lot, and made the puzzle more fun.

Comment: @Waterseas thanks, definitely should have.

Comment: I just lost the game.

Comment: @IanMacDonald did you get touched by Phage?

Comment: If we use Clever Impersonator to make our own Jace, may we assume that his -2 reveals whatever cards we want? May we subsequently assume that the opponent splits the piles however we want, or will the opponent split them to minimize our chances of success? If this is some unintended behaviour you don't want to be part of the puzzle, may I suggest replacing the opponent's Jace with a Cumber Stone?

Comment: @Ninety-Three great spot, I looked right over that. I'll remove the Jace from the board, but keep the activation

Comment: @Ninety-Three I considered a Dampening Pulse instead (or as you mentioned, Cumber Stone), but that card can be interacted with via Qasali Pridemage, where the Jace activation cannot be hampered

Comment: How are you guys doing? Been awfully quiet so far

Comment: The number of lines of play grows rather explosively, and there are multiple very different end states (killing each opponent with Poison counters or regular damage, or winning via Lab Maniac). I made one attempt, and after 12 Pod activations, I had dozens of options, and I had no idea whether any win state was viable.

Comment: @murgatroid99 yeah that was an interesting part of making it: in order to make it complicated, I had to increase the number of potential lines (directly as obfuscation, and indirectly as the length of the solution increased). If you guys feel I made it too hard, I could include a spoilered hint for those who wanted to know the wincon, to help narrow down the lines

Comment: I'm one play away from winning, so let me see if I can figure out how to fix that up...

Comment: Getting killed by "If a creature is copying something else, its converted mana cost is the converted mana cost of whatever it's copying.".

Comment: Well, unfortunately and unsurprisingly, I made a small mistake. I did not realize something about the way that one card works. I'm editing the puzzle with a slight addition to resolve this. Sorry for the messup, I went through the lines of play several times to check my math etc, but overlooked this one card. :( It should all be good now and sorry again

Comment: I beat your puzzle as originally stated, finally.  I don't need no second Academy Rector!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update: Now with formatting and links!**

The win condition is

> [Laboratory Maniac](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=230788), which makes sense, since he's the oddball out in this list.  Everything else is very Birthing Pod friendly.

I'll use [Pod 1 or 2] > [Thing Sacrificed] > [Thing Gotten] for shorthand.  Links are used to identify the *first* time a specific card is drawn or acquired.  Also, the [Plains](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=405341) and [Pull from Eternity](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=106657) were added later, so I'll be solving without their aid.  *(You can assume for this entire solution that I am holding Pull from Eternity in my hand and have my Plains untapped, if you wish)*

> Tap all your lands for mana floating - we'll be winning in this phase
>
>
>  ---
>
>
>  *Starting Resources: [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]] [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]] [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]], 25 life*
>
>
>  *Board: [Birthing Pod](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=218006) 1 (P1), [Birthing Pod](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=218006) 2 (P2), [Kitchen Finks](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370458)*
>
>
>  *Graveyard: [Necropede](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=194052)*
>
>
>  ---
>
>
>  P1 > Kitchen Finks > [Academy Rector](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=15138), persist Kitchen Finks, Kitchen Finks gets -1/-1, gain 2 life
>
>  [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]] [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]] [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]], 25 life
>
>
>  P2 > Academy Rector > [Sky Hussar](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=97109), exile Rector for [March of the Machines](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=220529), untap both Pods (thanks to March of the Machines making them creatures)
>
>  [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]] [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]] [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]], 23 life
>
>
>  P1 > Sky Hussar > [Auratouched Mage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=271207), finding and attaching [Nature's Chosen](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=3146)
>
>  [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]] [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]] [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]], 21 life
>
>
>  Tap Autatouched Mage to untap P1, using Nature's Chosen
>
>
>  P1 > Auratouched Mage > [Sepulchral Primordial](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=366285), grabbing [Lightning Mauler](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=271119) and [Voice of Resurgence](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=368951) from opponents' graveyards and putting them on the battlefield 
>
>  [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]] [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]] [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]], 19 life
>
>
>  P2 > Voice of Resurgence > [Village Bell-Ringer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=222923), get an [Elemental Token](http://shop.tcgplayer.com/magic/dragons-maze/elemental-token), untap both Pods
>
>  [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]] [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]] [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]], 17 life
>
>
>  P1 > Village Bell-Ringer > [Arcum Dagsson](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=122124)
>
>  [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]] [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]] [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]], 15 life
>
>
>  P2 > Arcum Dagsson > [Karmic Guide](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=382983), returning Village Bell-Ringer, untap both Pods
>
>  [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]] [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]] [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]], 13 life
>
>
>  P1 > Village Bell-Ringer > [Clever Impersonator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=386506), copying Karmic Guide, returning Arcum Daagsson, soulbond Arcum Daagsson with Lightning Mauler, giving both Haste
>
>  [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]] [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]] [image: ]][image: ]], 11 life
>
>
>  P2 > Karmic Guide > [Sun Titan](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=405400), returning Village Bell-Ringer, untap both Pods
>
>  [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]] [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]] [image: ]], 9 life
>
>
>  P1 > Village Bell-Ringer > [Phyrexian Metamorph](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=214375), copying Kitchen Finks, gain 2 life
>
>  [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]] [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]], 9 life
>
>
>  P2 > Elemental Token > [Hapless Researcher](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=36115)
>
>  [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]] [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]], 7 life
>
>
>  Tap Arcum Dagsson for his ability targeting Phyrexian Metamorph (Kitchen Finks), sacrifice Phyrexian Metamorph (Kitchen Finks) and replace it with [Cryptic Gateway](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=39701), persist Phyrexian Metamorph (Kitchen Finks), copying Sun Titan (with -1/-1), returning Village Bell-Ringer, untap both Pods and Arcum Dagsson
>
>
>  P1 > Phyrexian Metamorph (Sun Titan) (-1/-1) > [Angel of Serenity](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=405126), exiling Karmic Guide, Sky Hussar, and Phyrexian Metamorph
>
>  [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]] [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]], 5 life
>
>
>  P2 > Angel of Serenity > [Gigantomancer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=198172), returning Karmic Guide, Sky Hussar, and Phyrexian Metamorph to my hand
>
>  [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]] [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]], 3 life
>
>
>  Tap Arcum Dagsson and Gigantomancer to play Sky Hussar, untap both Pods, Arcum Dagsson, and Gigantomancer
>
>
>  P1 > Lightning Mauler > [Dross Harvester](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=50537), Arcum Dagsson no longer has haste
>
>  [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]] [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]], 1 life
>
>
>  ---
>
>
>  *Stabilization*
>
>
>  *Board: Birthing Pod 1, Birthing Pod 2, March of the Machines, Cryptic Gateway, Kitchen Finks (-1/-1), Sepulchral Primordial, Dross Harvester, Sun Titan, Humans: [Hapless Researcher, Arcum Dagsson, Gigantomancer, Village Bell-Ringer, Sky Hussar], Angels: [Clever Impersonator (Karmic Guide)]*
>
>
>  *Hand: Karmic Guide, Phyrexian Metamorph*
>
>
>  *Graveyard: Necropede, Auratouched Mage, Nature's Chosen, Angel of Serenity*
>
>
>  *Exile: Academy Rector*
>
>
>  ---
>
>
>  Sacrifice Hapless Researcher, draw and discard [Xenograft](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=227544), gain 2 life 
>
>  [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]] [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]], 3 life
>
>
>  Play Phyrexian Metamorph for RRR, pay 2 life, copy Clever Impersonator (Karmic Guide), return Hapless Researcher
>
>  [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]] [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]], 1 life
>
>
>  Sacrifice Hapless Researcher, draw and discard [Glistener Elf](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=233052), gain 2 life 
>
>  [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]] [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]], 3 life
>
>
>  *--- Beginning Loop One ---*
>
>
>  Tap Clever Impersonator (Karmic Guide), Phyrexian Metamorph (Karmic Guide) to play Karmic Guide using Cryptic Gateway, returning Angel of Serenity, exiling Karmic Guide, Village Bell-Ringer, and Hapless Researcher
>
>
>  P2 > Angel of Serenity > [Trench Gorger](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=228242) (exiling all 23 [Swamps](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=405402) in the deck), returning Karmic Guide, Village Bell-Ringer, and Hapless Researcher to my hand
>
>  [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]] [image: ]][image: ]], 3 life
>
>
>  Tap Arcum Dagsson and Gigantomancer to play Hapless Researcher using Cryptic Gateway
>
>
>  Tap Hapless Researcher and Sky Hussar to play Village Bell-Ringer using Cryptic Gateway, untapping both Pods, Clever Impersonator (Karmic Guide), Phyrexian Metamorph (Karmic Guide), Arcum Dagsson, Gigantomancer, Hapless Researcher and Sky Hussar
>
>
>  Sacrifice Hapless Researcher, draw and discard [Qasali Pridemage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=249405), gain 2 life
>
>  [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]] [image: ]][image: ]], 5 life
>
>
>  *--- Beginning Loop Two ---*
>
>
>  Tap Clever Impersonator (Karmic Guide), Phyrexian Metamorph (Karmic Guide), to play Karmic Guide using Cryptic Gateway, return Angel of Serenity, exiling Karmic Guide, Village Bell-Ringer, and Hapless Researcher
>
>
>  P1 > Angel of Serenity > [Fail to Find], returning Karmic Guide, Village Bell-Ringer, and Hapless Researcher to my hand
>
>  [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]] [image: ]], 5 life
>
>
>  P2 > Sun Titan > [Boonweaver Giant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=383194), finding and attaching [Shade's Form](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=23043)
>
>  [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]], 5 life
>
>
>  Tap Arcum Dagsson and Gigantomancer to play Hapless Researcher using Cryptic Gateway
>
>
>  Tap Hapless Researcher and Sky Hussar to play Village Bell-Ringer using Cryptic Gateway, untapping both Pods, Clever Impersonator (Karmic Guide), Phyrexian Metamorph (Karmic Guide), Arcum Dagsson, Gigantomancer, Hapless Researcher and Sky Hussar
>
>
>  Sacrifice Hapless Researcher, draw and discard [Kathari Bomber](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=386337), gain 2 life
>
>  [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]], 7 life
>
>
>  *--- Beginning Loop Three ---*
>
>
>  Tap Clever Impersonator (Karmic Guide), Phyrexian Metamorph (Karmic Guide), to play Karmic Guide using Cryptic Gateway, return Angel of Serenity, exiling Karmic Guide, Village Bell-Ringer, and Hapless Researcher
>
>
>  P1 > Angel of Serenity > [Fail to Find], returning Karmic Guide, Village Bell-Ringer, and Hapless Researcher to my hand
>
>  [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]], 7 life
>
>
>  Tap Arcum Dagsson and Gigantomancer to play Hapless Researcher using Cryptic Gateway
>
>
>  P2 > Arcum Dagsson > [Phyrexian Delver](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=376446), return Qasali Pridemage, lose 2 life
>
>  [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]], 5 life
>
>
>  Tap Hapless Researcher and Sky Hussar to play Village Bell-Ringer using Cryptic Gateway, untapping both Pods, Clever Impersonator (Karmic Guide), Phyrexian Metamorph (Karmic Guide), Gigantomancer, Hapless Researcher and Sky Hussar
>
>
>  P1 > Qasali Pridemage > [Laboratory Maniac](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=230788)
>
>  [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]], 5 life
>
>
>  At this point, your deck is now empty
>
>
>  Sacrifice Hapless Researcher with an empty deck and Laboratory Maniac in play, gain 2 life, win the game!
>
>
>  ---
>
>
>  *Remaining Resources: [image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]][image: ]], 7 life, Karmic Guide in hand, 0 cards in deck, a bunch of junk on the battlefield*
>
>
>  ---

Comment: "Sepulchral Primordial, grabbing Lightning Mauler, Voice of Resurgence, and Hero of Bladehold from opponents' and putting them on the battlefield" You appear to be rezzing three creatures, which is not how the Primordial works.

Comment: Right you are.  Corrected that, I think it's all good now... though it'll take me another hour to confirm that for sure.

Comment: Alright, on about the 10th try, I think it works (original answer was correct in spirit, incorrect in the details).  I'll probably find out otherwise in the morning, but I need sleep - getting nerd sniped too hard here.

Comment: Your solution almost works, but you're illegally casting Metamorph for RRRR. You can only pay RRRU, or RRR + 2 life. You don't have U, and if you pay 2, you won't have enough life to keep activating Pod.

Comment: Right you are.  Fixed it, and found a much more efficient solution in the process, which even has a lot of resources left over!  (Although, this being attempt #15 and short on sleep, I don't promise I haven't missed something...)

Comment: At the very end of your solution you're using Pod1 twice without untapping it.

Comment: Good catch, easy fix - I'm in a full loop at that point anyway.

Comment: It doesn't actually matter in your solution, as far as I can tell, but I want to note that when you have Dross Harvester in play, you pay 2 life to activate Birthing Pod and then gain the life back with Harvester. If you ever do that at 2 or less life, the payment puts you at 0 or less life and makes you lose before the Harvester can save you.

Comment: Entirely correct - it actually matters a fair bit; my latest version is hovering on one life much of time.  You can double check, but I don't believe I ever activate Pod when I have 2 or less.

Comment: Not the same way I did it, but I can't spot anything wrong with this one and you even end up with spare mana! Great work and don't worry, I'll ease back up on the difficulty of these (at least in terms of length)

Comment: @NeedAName It wasn't the difficulty so much as the length that was an obstacle here. The puzzle's too big to hold in your head all at once, so I found myself resorting to a lot of "What if I make these five moves, does that work?" guess and check where I didn't have a good sense of where I was going.

Comment: Yeah - I knew instantly what the win condition was (Maniac) and what the stabilization condition was (Dross), but it took me quite a while to find the loop condition (Angel) and to figure out how to stabilize in time.