# Magic: the Gathering - Challenge #6: Going Mental

Tags: calculation-puzzle, magic-the-gathering

<sub>[Previous Challenge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24081/magic-the-gathering-challenge-5-what-if-pod-was-one-of-us)</sub>

### Background

Today's puzzle is going to involve Mental Magic, a fun, memory-testing variant of magic. All of magic's usual rules apply, but with the following variations

- Any card in your hand may be played face down as a land that taps for any color of mana. This land is treated as basic with no subtypes. (Usual land-per-turn rule applies)
- Any card may be played as any other nonland MtG card as long as

  - that card does not have the same name
  - that card has the exact same mana cost (note: this includes color symbols, hybrid mana, X-cost, etc.) so e.g. Wild Guess can be cast as Eidolon of the Great Revel, but not as Rolling Thunder and Thoughtseize can be cast as Gravecrawler, but not as Deathrite Shaman.
- The same spell may not be cast more than once in a game

Some additional house rules for simplicity:

- Search effects are banned. This includes cards like Entomb and also cards where only part of the effect involves searching e.g. Sever the Bloodline
- Cards in hand/library have no name, only their printed (sub)types and costs so no exiling an Elvish Spirit Guide or cycling Street Wraith
- We'll be playing a Legacy game of Mental Magic, meaning that the Legacy banned list and rules should be observed.

### Puzzle Setup

It's turn 1 and you're on the play. Let's assume that (magically) your opponent has no cards in hand. Win this turn with the rules given above and the hand and library below. Both boards and graveyards are empty. If your require interaction with your opponent's library (remember that searching is banned) you may assume the card type(s) required are there. Your solution must be a guaranteed win, not involving your opponent self-destructing (e.g. they choose 20 on a Choice of Damanations) or random chance (you Hymn to Tourach yourself and hit the right 2 cards). If multiple solutions are achieved, the one that does the most damage wins.

**Your hand:**
Cabal Ritual x 2 (**1B**)
Candelabra of Tawnos (**1**)
Doomsday (**BBB**)
Reanimate x 3 (**B**)

**Your library: (top to bottom)**
Reanimate (**B**)
Tarmogoyf (**1G**)
Council's Judgment (**1WW**)
Lightning Bolt (**R**)
Brainstorm (**U**)
Hymn to Tourach (**BB**)
Glimpse of Nature (**G**)

EDIT: There's been a lot of confusion surrounding the not-very-well-defined parameters I provided. In an attempt to clarify this, I've posted what I believe to be a more clear, more well-defined version [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24240/magic-the-gathering-challenge-6-b)

Comment: "Let's assume that your opponent has no cards in library" "win this turn". Okay, I do nothing and he top-decks himself. ;)

Comment: @IanMacDonald nice try, that's why I specified win this turn ;p

Comment: @NeedAName then it's also easy. Just cast any "target player draws cards" spell on your opponent :P

Comment: @IvoBeckers those are surprisingly thin on the ground in those mana costs...

Comment: lol good point. Fine then. Edited the post to cover this error

Comment: @histocrat just cast Brainstorm as a Ancestral Recall

Comment: I don't understand the necessity of sub-rule "that card does not have the same name". Why is this rule necessary?

Comment: Ah, I figured the challenge was to dig far enough to get to the U or BB. Guess that's too simple. :p

Comment: "Any card may be played as any other nonland MtG card as long as that card does not have the same name" with this "Cards in hand/library have no name". :O

Comment: @IanMacDonald that is a bit of a nombo. The rules on mental magic are not super well developed and my wording wasn't great. If you have an alternative to get the point that I'm trying to make, please feel free to edit. Like, once it is placed on the stack as cast, it has a name? idk

Comment: I guess that would depend on what the meaning of the first rule of those two rules is. Is the intention that "You cannot play Reanimate, but you can play any spell that costs B." (for example)?

Comment: @IanMacDonald yes. You may cast reanimate as any spell that costs exactly B, with the exception of reanimate itself

Comment: How are cards in the graveyard treated? Notable interactions: dregscape zombie, macabre waltz, and things with dredge or discard that put unplayed cards in the graveyard.

Comment: Cards in graveyard can be named for flashback (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Magic:_The_Gathering/Mental_Magic_Format), for example a Fact or Fiction in the gy can be flashbacked as a Deep Analysis. I imagine the same would fly for unearth, recover, etc. Unless otherwise interacted with, I guess the card just has its (sub)type(s).

Comment: May the same card be referred to more than once if the references dont involve casting it? I.e. get two creatures from your graveyard to put in hand or on the battlefield, name the same creature for both cards.

Comment: @Zerris that's a great question and I don't know if it's well defined; based on the discussion I found online, they should have to be the card that they really are when they enter the battlefield

Comment: Why is it allowed to count the cards in your graveyard as creatures? It's nowhere in the rules I think. And two answers so far use this possibility and it seems you seem fine with it

Comment: Does the opponent have a library? I may be able to improve my answer if the opponent has an empty library.

Comment: @IvoBeckers to be honest, I sort of got in over my head by choosing mental magic. I could have kept it simpler and said that you have to use cards with the given mana costs, I overlooked all of the particulars of mental magic. But I've made my bed so I feel obligated to sleep in it (there are too many answers built on the premise so far)

Comment: @IvoBeckers I figured we were allowed to count creatures in graveyard as an extension of the philosophy that lets you use cards in graveyard for Flashback.

Comment: @NeedAName It turns out you won't need to sleep in that particular bed, because you can deal infinite damage without any "counting stuff in a graveyard" shenanigans, except for triggered abilities which you allowed in your comment regarding Recover.

Answer (score 3):

Think I figured out a line.

1. Doomsday as land
2. Play (reanimate) dark ritual
3. Play (reanimate) blood pet
4. Play (reanimate) culling the weak and sac blood pet (BBBBB)
5. Play (candelabra) cromantic star and sac for G (floating BBBG) draw card
6. Play (reanimate) song of the damned and name all 4 cards in your yard as critters go to BBBBBB G floating
7. Play (cabal ritual) plunge into darkness and pay 19 life.  Take the glimpse.
8. Play (cabal ritual) shallow grave, pick (reanimate) death's shadow as the card
9. Attack and play (glimpse of nature) berserk to deal 24 (edit math fail)

Easy game.

Comment: Went ahead and edited to add new lines (you have to put two spaces at the end of a line to make new line).

Comment: That is... very good. You can get one more B by declaring Song of the Damned a creature as it resolves, but it doesn't really matter.  I couldn't find any loops in these mana costs yet, so I suspect straight up damage will win and 38's not bad.  Beats anything I was going to do with Pack Rats and Rites of Initiation.

Comment: This beats my intended solution of 31 damage. @Zerris what you mentioned wouldn't work since Song wouldn't be in the gy until done resolving (therefore not counting itself). Actually, now that I reread it, how do you do 38 damage? Death's Shadow is a 12/12 if you're at 1 life so where does the other 14 damage come from?

Comment: Oh, you're right, it resolves first then goes places.  I really want a training grounds / pack rat solution here, but it's so hard to set up any mana cycles in mental magic, especially when everything costs the same...

Comment: Hm. I don't think Song of the Damned or Culling the Weak works here. "Cards in hand/library have no name, only their printed (sub)types and costs" implies that the Reanimates will all still be sorcery type no matter what.

Answer (score 2):

Update: I finally did it, a solution all my own that deals infinite damage, without counting anything as having a card type not printed on it (even for targeting purposes). As OP stated in the comments of the question, Recover works, which is a triggered ability belonging to a card in a graveyard. Based on this, I will be using the triggered abilities of several cards in graveyards. Since I am not casting these cards, they do not become unusable.

Starting Hand: 1, B, B, B, 1B, 1B, BBB
1: Play Reanimate as land, tap it for (B)
2: Cast [Dark Ritual](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397401) (BBB)
3: Cast [Cast Carnival of Souls](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=19115) (B)
4: Cast [Myr Moonvessel](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=46112), Carnival triggers (B)
5: Cast [Culling the Weak](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=6085), sacrificing Moonvessel (1BBBB)
6: Cast [Cruel Bargain](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=382901), drawing Reanimate, dredging Reanimate as Darkblast (milling Tarmogoyf, Council's Judgement and Lightning Bolt), drawing Brainstorm and Hymn to Tourach (1B)
7: Cast [Blood Artist](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=240178), Carnival triggers (B)
8: Cast [Viscera Seer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=376569), Carnival triggers (B)
9: Cast [Blood Pet](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=25625), Carnival triggers, sacrifice it, Doomsday in the graveyard triggers as [Bridge from Below](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370353), you get a token, Carnival triggers (BBB)
10: Cast [Distress](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=236908) on the opponent just to get it into the graveyard (B)
11: Sacrifice a token, Hymn to Tourach in the graveyard triggers as [Nether Traitor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=116742), pay to bring it back, Carnival triggers
12: Sacrifice Nether Shadow, Bridge triggers, Carnival triggers.
13: Return to step 11, repeat infinitely for infinite Blood Artist triggers and infinite mana.

Edit: Previous solution was wrong due to an illegal dredge, fixed now.

Comment: I figured out how to discard the hymn. It involves using Rain of Filth pre-Song, then using Macabre Waltz to pitch the damn thing. But it's 5 AM and I'm going to bed, will update solution in the morning.

Comment: Technically this is only 35 dmg, since he dies before the other 35. Better to berserk after first strike damage

Comment: Currently on vacation, so no time to post big things, so thought i'd leave this idea with you, which would've been my answer, and can combo infinitely : Retribution of the ancients, Geralf's Messenger (or any other undying creature if you use blood artist), Carnival of souls (!!!!) and a sac outlet (viscera seer?) + a life gain engine (essence warden/blood artist)

Comment: @DrunkWolf Why is it only 35 damage? Berserk kills in the end step.

Comment: because opponent only has 20 life and dies before normal combat damage step :) not sure how we count that though ;)

Comment: @DrunkWolf Oh riiiight. I suppose if we're counting that way, your Carnival of Souls combo (good job on that, I was stuck trying to use it with No Rest for the Wicked somehow) really only does 20, then they die with the rest of the triggers on the stack. I'm trying to build a version of that combo using Rot Shambler for actually infinite damage.

Comment: i'm really not sure how it's being counted, up to the OP to decide

Comment: @DrunkWolf doesn't matter how it's counted, now using Carrion Feeder. You have no idea how stupid and elaborate my six-card Rot Shambler solution was, before I realized I could just replace Viscera Seer and Rot Shambler with the Feeder.

Comment: How are you using Dredge without Darkblast being in your graveyard?

Comment: I'm treating Reanimate as the identically costed Darkblast. Given that OP said you can Flashback and Recover, Dredge seems reasonable.

Comment: How can you cast blood artist? You used 1B's on land and carnaval

Comment: @DrunkWolf Woops. The thing went through a million edits. I should be playing Reanimate as land. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

On a phone, so I'll fix formatting later.

1B - land

Tap for B

B - Dark Ritual

B - Blood Celebrant

Pay B, 1 Life: R

B - Culling the Weak

BBB - Cruel Bargain, draw 4, lose 10 life

R - Mana Clash

Opponent flips 20 tails before you flip 9, and you never both flip heads - you win!

Comment: Forgot to copy over the usual corollary regarding guaranteed wins. Thanks for catching that

Answer (score -1):

Play Candelabra of Tawnos facedown.
Tap [facedown] for B. (pool: B)
Play Reanimate as [Dark Ritual](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=221510). (pool: BBB)
Play Reanimate as [Dark Ritual](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=221510). (pool: BBBBB)
Play Doomsday as [Geralf's Messenger](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=243250). (pool: BB)
Play Reanimate as [Retribution of the Ancients](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=386635). (pool: B)
....win
Play Cabal Ritual as [Bloodthrone Vampire](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=198308). (pool: -1)

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE!  Can you please flesh out your answer a little more to explain *how* your solution works?

Comment: Can't use dark ritual twice in mental magic.

Comment: I've updated your answer to add links to it and spell out mana costs. I wasn't able to follow how you won, so I didn't attempt to expand on it. Also, you don't have enough mana to cast all the spells you listed (in addition to breaking the "no duplicates" rule).

Comment: He thinks he won because he forgot Retribution of the Ancients had an activation mana cost. It would work if there was a phyrexian altar.