# Magic: the Gathering - Challenge #7: In Your Dreams

Tags: calculation-puzzle, magic-the-gathering

<sub>[Previous Challenge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24240/magic-the-gathering-challenge-6-b-its-gonna-cost-you)</sub>

### Background

Normal MtG rules apply here. You may not assume that your opponent will cooperate with you (e.g. choose not to block any of your creatures when they can). Assume that your opponent will block the largest power creatures that they legally can with as many creatures as they legally can, regardless of whether or not it will kill their blockers (in the event of tied power, assume they choose to block the first of the tied attackers alphabetically). If you would draw a card, you may assume that you draw any card remaining in your library, regardless of shuffling.

### Puzzle Setup

It's your main phase 1, you haven't played a land for the turn. You're being demolished by your opponent and they have you dead next turn: reverse the tides and win this turn! You've just cast [Three Dreams](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=275260) and are about to resolve it. Good luck!

**Your hand:**
Nothing

**Your board:**
Nothing

**Your graveyard:**
[Aura Shards](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=247184)
[Auramancer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=398678)
[Eternal Witness](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=405216)

**Your library:**
[Abduction](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=14526)
[Animate Dead](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=382843)
[Battle Mastery](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=394506)
[Daybreak Coronet](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397798)
[Dragon Fangs](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=47165)
[Dual Casting](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=240138)
[Empyrial Armor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=382923)
[Enslave](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=393887)
[Fallen Ideal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=405227)
[Field of Reality](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=50272)
[Flight of Fancy](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=83677)
[Galvanic Arc](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=87968)
[Hammerhand](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=383262)
[Infiltrator's Magemark](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=107684)
[Mirror Mockery](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=394625)
[Nature's Chosen](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=3146)
[Necromancer's Magemark](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=107685)
[Righteous Authority](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=253546)
[Sisay's Ingenuity](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=26407)
[Spirit Loop](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=109680)
[Splinter Twin](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397816)
[Triclopean Sight](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=146580)
[Vow of Malice](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=405445)
[Vow of Wildness](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=238135)

**Your life:**
1

**Your mana:**
[image: ]]: 41
[image: ]]: 11
[image: ]]: 8
[image: ]]: 3
[image: ]]: 7
[image: ]]: 1

**Opponent's hand:**
Nothing

**Opponent's board: (all untapped, summoning sick)**
[Aether Membrane](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=270856)
[Arashi, the Sky Asunder](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=87333)
[Drift of Phantasms](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=87994)
[Pillar of War](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=378532)

**Opponent's graveyard:**
Nothing

**Opponent's library:**
60 Swamp

**Opponent's life:**
60

**Opponent's mana:**
Nothing

Comment: How are you losing if your opponent's deck is all swamps except for four cards? ;)

Comment: @orp Earlier in the game you cast Delay (which later got exiled) on your opponent's Trench Gorger, their Flame-kin Zealot, and their Ondu Champion, and they're about to come off Suspend!

Comment: @NeedAName Since you seem so interested in Magic puzzles, would you be interested in playing a game of Zero Variance? It's a chess-like variant of Mental Magic devised by Patrick Chapin, and one that I have trouble finding people to play with. Basically, Mental Magic where each card can be anything, not just anything with the same mana cost (additionally, preventing things from getting stupid and confusing in the way Mental Magic can: no graveyards, and only cast one spell per turn)

Comment: @Ninety-Three based on what I've read, that sounds too intense for me lol I really like the idea, but think it's something I'd rather watch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like I found an answer far easier than intended. EDIT: Here's a solution that deals 78 damage.

Resolve Three Dreams (hand: 3 cards)
Cast Animate dead, returning Eternal Witness, getting back Three Dreams
Cast Three Dreams (hand: 5 cards)
32 C
9 W
8 U
2 B
7 R
1 G
Cast Hammerhand on Eternal Witness (trigger targets Drift of Phantasms). Cast Splinter Twin on Eternal Witness, activate it, get back Three Dreams
Cast Dual Casting on the Eternal Witness token, then cast Dual Cast Three Dreams (hand: 8)
25 C
8 W
8 U
2 B
2 R
1 G
Cast Triclopean Sight on the Twin Witness to untap it
Activate Twin for a token to get back Auramancer (hand: 7 + Aurmancer)
24 C
7 W
8 U
2 B
2 R
1 G
Play Fallen Ideal on the new Witness token.
Play Abduction on Twin Witness, untapping it.
Activate Twin, then with the trigger on the stack, sacrifice the Twin Witness to Fallen Ideal.
Abduction triggers, bringing back Eternal Witness, bringing back Abduction.
Splinter Twin resolves, you get a token, bringing back Three Dreams.
Board: Fallen Token (4/2), Dualcaster Token, Plain Token, Original Witness
Hand: 5 + Auramancer, Three Dreams, Abduction
20 C
7 W
6 U
1 B
2 R
1 G
Play Nature's Chosen on the Dualcaster, untap it.
Dualcast Three Dreams (hand: 10 + Auramancer, Abduction)
16 C
6 W
6 U
1 B
1 R
Sacrifice Original Witness to Fallen Ideal.
Cast Auramancer for Animate Dead.
Cast Animate Dead for Witness, for Three Dreams (hand: 10 + Abduction, Three Dreams)
Board: Fallen Token (6/3), Dualcaster Token, Plain Token, Original Witness, Auramancer
13 C
5 W
6 U
1 R
Cast Three Dreams (hand: 13 + Abduction)
Cast Battle Mastery, Righteous Authority, Empyrial Armor, Mirror Mockery on Fallen Token (hand: 9 + Abduction)
2 C
4 U
1 R
Cast Abduction on Auramancer
Sacrifice Auramancer (8/4), abduction triggers, bringing back Auramancer, getting back Hammerhand
Cast Hammerhand on Fallen Token, trigger targets Aether Membrane (hand: 9)
Attack with Fallen token (opp has no flying blockers because of Hammerhand triggers), Mirror Mockery triggers, token gets back Three Dreams (hand:10)
Sacrifice all five creatures, attacker is 2 base + 16 Ideal + 1 Hammerhand + 10 Armor + 10 Authority. 78 damage with Double Strike.

@NeedAName mentioned that this solution is easier than intended because Arashi doesn't have flying, you can adapt this solution to beat a flying Arashi by Witnessing back Abduction instead of Three Dreams and Abducting the opponent's Arashi (you lose 8 damage, but the solution can then be optimized to save a bit of mana so that you can cast Flight of Fancy for the draw 2, so you only lose 4 damage).

Comment: You did in fact find a solution easier than intended. Part of this was me putting Arashi instead of a third flyer as I had intended. That said, still a fine solution, and I'm not going to backtrack on this one. I wonder how much damage could be improved?

Comment: Cast Splinter Twin on Eternal Witness, activate it, get back Three Dreams.
- How exactly? Witness has summoning sickness.

Comment: @DrunkWolf Woops. Supposed to be Hammerhanding it there, will edit to fix.

Comment: @NeedAName found a solution that deals 70, and would beat a flying Arashi. Not significantly more complicated. Will post in a few hours.

Comment: @NeedAName Here's the new solution, 78 damage per original challenge or 74 + beats a flying Arashi. There are so many auras that return to your hand, I suspect your solution used them somehow, if so I'd be curious to see it.